# Which Green Lantern characters appear in war with Darkseid?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, dc-animated-movie-universe, justice-league-dark-apokolips-war

In the movie *Justice League Dark: Apokolips War* when Darkseid attacks the planet of Oa he has a fight with members of the Green Lantern Corps. There were 4-5 members who are killed by Darkseid in the fight. They appear to be important members of the Green Lantern Corps. Which members were present there in the fight with Darkseid, help me identify them by naming them?

The images of the Green Lanterns from the fight are given below
[image: A Green Lantern lies prone on the ground, looking up. His suit is torn at the left shoulder and right arm and he is missing his mask. He is bleeding from the gashes in his left shoulder, the gash in his right arm and from his forehead and mouth. He holds his Green Lantern ring in his right fist in front of him.]

[image: Three Green Lanterns charge forward, leading with their rings on their right fists. On the left is a Green Lantern that looks like a giant head with arms growing where a human's ears would be. In the middle is a brown-haired and bearded humanoid with pointed ears, and on the right the Green Lantern is white-skinned and hairless with an egg-shaped skull dome and a heavy jaw-line.]

[image: Darkseid stands facing forward and right, gesturing with his right hand. Behind his left shoulder, a muscular Green Lantern with red eyes, a huge head, a heavy brow ridge, a short flared nose and a massive jaw is diving on him.]

Comment: For a second I was wondering if this question was worth upvoting. Then I came to the conclusion that I don't know all their names and I wouldn't know where to start looking either if Wikipedia and any fandom wiki were inaccurate and/or incomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### These are the GLs from your images

Image 1: [John Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Stewart_(character))

[image: John Stewart]

---

Image 2 Three GLs(left to right):

1. [Galius Zed](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Galius_Zed)

[image: Galius Zed]

2. [Arkkis Chummuck](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Arkkis_Chummuck)

[image: Arkkis Chummuck]

3. [Green Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Man_(character))

[image: Green Man]

---

Image 3: The GL jumping on Darkseid [Kilowog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilowog)

[image: Kilowog]

---

NOTE: ***All images taken from Justice League: The Animated Series***

---

**PS**: In addition to the GLs in your question, the other lanterns in the movie are mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_Dark:_Apokolips_War) (apart from John and Kilowog as they are quite well-known):

> [...] members of the Green Lantern Corps (Arisia Rrab, Arkkis Chummuck, Chaselon, Galius Zed, Green Man, Guy Gardner, Palaqua, and Salaak) all have non-speaking roles and cameos, being left as minor characters.

Answer (score 6):

All the Green Lanterns that appear in the movie are:

[Arisia](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Arisia)

[image: Arisia appears to be lying on the ground. She has short blonde hair and she is facing down with her eyes closed. She is wearing a sleeveless suit with elbow-length green gloves. There appears be be a fire behind her.]

[Arkkis Chummuck](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Arkkis_Chummuck)

[image: Arkkis is charging toward the viewer, caught in a leap. He is leading with his right fist, the Green Lantern ring featuring prominently. His left fist is cocked at his side and he is grimacing. In appearance he has pointed ears, a tufted brown beard and sideburns, and 2 wing-like tufts of hair on his forehead.]

[Chaselon](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Chaselon)

[image: Chaselon appears to be a white faceted being with an orange mohawk and tentacular limbs.]

[Galius Zed](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Galius_Zed)

[image: A frowning Galius Zed is charging a foe offscreen to the left. He appears to be a large head with limbs directly attached to it.]

[Green Man](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Man)

[image: Green Man is also leaping into battle, leading with his left hand and his Green Lantern ring. He has a very pale face against which his Green Lantern mask contrasts starkly.]

[Guy Gardner](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_(Guy_Gardner))

[image: Guy Gardner is laying on his back, apparently unconscious. He is wearing a sleeveless Green Lantern tunic and no mask. He has short brown hair and a strong, clean-shaven jawline.]

[John Stewart](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_(John_Stewart))

[image: Jon Stewart is laying prone, conscious but injured. Blood drips from his forehead and mouth. His suit has multiple rips, exposing his left shoulder which has 2 deep, bleeding gashes. There is a gash on his right upper arm. He is mask-less, but holds his Green Lantern ring forward on his right fist.]

[Kilowog](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Kilowog)

[image: Kilowog is leaping to attack Darkseid from the left and just behind his shoulder. Kilowog has red glinting eyes deep set in a huge cranial ridge and an outsized mouth in his wide face.]

[Palaqua](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Palaqua) (not 100% sure on this one)

[image: Palaqua is indistinct, but lying supine, arm extended to the side and bent at the elbow, head rolled to the left.]

[Salakk](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Salaak)

[image: Salakk is flopped prone over something in the air, with its legs and arms dangling in the air. Salakk has a tall, pink-skinned head with a ridge at the midline.]

Comment: Although I ain't sure either, that is indeed Palaqua (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_Dark:_Apokolips_War)

Comment: @Shreedhar he's in the movie, and this was the last lantern i could not identify so haha.